# While loop just repeats

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

So my program is meant to run infinite times until the user enters -999. With this current set up all that happens when any number is entered is it spews out all the text and ignores whatever is entered.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Local Variable Declaration//

        const double rate1 = 10;
        const double rate2 = 3;
        const double maxCharge = 50;
        double charge;
        int hoursRented;


        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of hours (-999 to quit) : ");
            hoursRented = Console.Read();
            if (hoursRented == -999)
                break;

            else

                if (hoursRented <= 3)
            {
                charge = hoursRented * rate1;
            }
            else
            {
                charge = (3 * rate1) + ((hoursRented - 3) * rate2);
            }

            if (charge > maxCharge)
            {
                charge = maxCharge;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Are you a member? (Y/N) : ");
            string memberStatus = Console.ReadLine();
            string upperstring = memberStatus.ToUpper();
            if (memberStatus.Equals("Y"))
            {
                charge = charge - (charge * 1 / 10);
            }

            double TotalCharge = +charge;

            Console.WriteLine("Customer Charge : {0}   Total Charge To Date {1} :  ", charge, TotalCharge);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: BTW, when you use `while` you're meant to use a flag to exit the loop... `while(continue)` and at some point `continue = false`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer OP already has a `break` statement.  Whether or not the preceding logic is correct is an entirely different case ;)

Comment: Have you tried with `Console.ReadLine()` instead `Console.Read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the documentation for `Console.Read`:

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream.

The method reads only a single character. To read an entire line, use [`ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
int hours;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hours) && hours == -999)
    break;
```